# Why we use UseConnectionLogging in asp.net core's kestrel configuration and how it is work?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I'm a beginner in asp.net core and i saw a code in a project which using UseConnectionLogging in kestrel configuration, i want to know that how it is work and why we use this.

```
options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 5001, listenOptions =>
{
     listenOptions.UseConnectionLogging();
});
```